# Prove that the line integral on $\beta$ of $f'(z)/f(z) = (A-B)/2 \pi i$ using Rouche's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots

Suppose that $\alpha$ is a regular closed contour. $f$, our function, lacks zeros and poles on $\beta$ and if A=the number of zeros of f inside $\beta$ (a zero of order n is counted n times) and B= the number of poles of f inside $\beta$ (same idea with counting multiplicity).  Prove that the line integral on $\beta$ of $f'(z)/f(z) = (A-B)/2 \pi i$.

I'm not really sure how to proceed with this proof.  If someone can give me a hint or some direction that would be really appreciated.

Comment: ...and $\;\beta\;$ is...?

Comment: If $f$ has a zero of degree $m$ at $z_0$ then we can write $f(z) = (z-z_0)^mg(z)$ with $g(z_0)\not = 0$. Then $f'/f = \ldots$

Comment: Do you **have** to use Rouche's Theorem? Because this is just  the (Cauchy's)  Argument Principle...and btw,: it must be that the integral of $\;f'/f\;$ equals $\;2\pi i(A-B)\;$ .

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;Z_i\,,\,P_j\;$ be little, *non-overlapping nor intersecting* circles around the zeros and poles, resp. of $\;f(z)\;$ in the domain determined by $\;\alpha\;$ . then

$$\oint_\alpha\frac{f'}fdz=\sum_{i=1}^n\oint_{Z_i}\frac{f'}fdz+\sum_{j=1}^m\oint_{P_i}\frac{f'}fdz$$

Now, if the zeros are $\;\{z_1,...,z_k\}\;$ with respectives multiplicities $\;n_1,...,n_k\;$ ,  and the poles are $\;\{p_1,...,p_m\}\;$ with respective multiplicities $\;t_1,...,t_m\;$ (and thus we have that $\;A=\sum\limits_{i=1}^kn_i\,,\,\,B=\sum\limits_{j=1}^mt_j\;$),  we can then write

$$\begin{align}&\text{Around}\;z_i\;:\;\;f(z)=(z-z_i)^{n_i}g_i(z)\implies f'(z)=n_i(z-z_i)^{n_i-1}g(z)+(z-z_i)^{n_i}g'(z)\\{}\\&\text{Around}\;p_j\;:\;\;f(z)=\frac{h(z)}{(z-p_j)^{t_j}}\implies f'(z)=\frac{h'(z)(z-p_j)-t_jh(z)}{(z-p_j)^{t_j+1}}\end{align}$$

with $\;g_i\,,\,h_j\;$ holomorphic functions without zeros, poles resp. in the region limited by $\;Z_i\,,\,\,P_i\;$  resp.

Thus, for each $\;i\,,\,j\;$ we get

$$\oint_{Z_i}\frac{f'}fdz=\int_{Z_i}\frac{n_i}{z-z_i}dz+\oint_{Z_i}\frac{g'}gdz=2\pi i n_i+0$$

and likewise for the other integrals, using Cauchy's theorem and etc. Complete and fill in details in the argument now.